# Dhtmlx Scheduler Inside a Multisteps Form

Tags: javascript, forms, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm using this multi-step form: https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz

I've included a scheduler inside the second `<fieldset>` of the form.

But when I click the `next` button, the scheduler appears empty.

[image: picture of the scheduler that doesn't show]

When I resize the navigator manually, the events and the scheduler show normally.

The CSS body is set to `height:100%`.

Finally, the behavior is still abnormal, when I'm clicking on a day:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById is null
```

When I'm not using the multi steps, it is working. Does anyone have any idea about what is wrong?

Comment: Please embed some critical code directly inside the question. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: The code works when it is used outside multi step form. It is the standard DHTMLX api.